# How to add a gps plugin using gazebo ui?

Tags: ros, ros-gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have an iRobot Create that I could spawn into gazebo, and I would like to add a gps plugin to it in gazebo so as to send the robot to a specific gps location (within gazebo-world).

Any help with this, would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15017/how-to-add-a-gps-plugin-using-gazebo-ui?/) by [nerdyTurtle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2968/nerdyturtle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, there's no easy way of doing this through the UI at the moment.

Your best bet is to directly edit the SDF file to add the sensor plugin. [This](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor) tutorial has a contact sensor plugin example.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0